# Solve $\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

My initial idea was
$$(\sin(x)\cos(x))^2=1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
Let $t=\sin(x)\cos(x)$;
$$t^2=1+2t \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad t=1-\sqrt2$$
(since $1+\sqrt2>1$).
I.e.
$$\sin(x)\cos(x)=1-\sqrt2 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \tfrac12\sin(2x)=1-\sqrt2 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad x=\tfrac{1}{2}\arcsin(2(1-\sqrt2))$$
but I didn't get any ‘elegant’ final solution. Any better ideas?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your working out is correct, except for  there being infinitely many solutions: $x = \frac{1}{2}(\arcsin(2(1-\sqrt{2})) + 2k\pi), \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: [WolframAlpha also can't find a simpler form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin%282x%29%20%3D%202-2*sqrt%282%29 "WolframAlpha")

Comment: "since $1+\sqrt2>1$", should be "since $1+\sqrt2>0.5$"

Comment: RamanujanXV. Yes, thank you.

Comment: One problem. E.g. $x_0=-0.488147$ is not a solution. The error comes from the quadration. How to eliminate these?

Comment: The problem can be solved by using $t=\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and then solve for $x.$

Comment: Reinhard Meier. Could you please show?

Comment: @mf67  $t=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ results in $x=\arcsin(t/\sqrt{2})+2\pi n -\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $x=(2n+1)\pi - \arcsin(t/\sqrt{2}) -\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: In general, an equivalence like the last one in the question must not only have a "${}+2k\pi$" term to account for the fact that $\sin(y)=\sin(y+2k\pi),$ it must also include an alternative sequence of solutions due to the fact that $\sin(y) = \sin(\pi-y).$ In this particular problem, half of the "solutions" in each of these sequences are correct and the other half come from the loss of sign information when squaring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

You can also proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(x) + \cos(x) & \Longleftrightarrow 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = 2(\sin(x) + \cos(x))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 1 + 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = 1 + 2(\sin(x) + \cos(x))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\sin(x) + \cos(x))^{2} = 1 + 2(\sin(x) + \cos(x))
\end{align*}

Then make the change of variable $t = \sin(x) + \cos(x)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Finally!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)-\cos(x)$$ To avoid squaring, use the tangent half-angle formula $x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$ and you need to solve for $t$ the quartic
$$t^4-4t^3-1=0$$ which shows two real solutions
$$t_\pm=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(5+4 \sqrt{2}\right)}$$ which is not better but does not contain any falso root due to squaring.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\dfrac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}=\cos\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)$

$\implies -1\le y\le1$

$y^2=\dfrac{1+2\sin x\cos x}2$

We have $$\dfrac{y^2-1}2=\sqrt2y\implies y^2-2\sqrt2y-1=0$$

$$y= \sqrt2\pm\sqrt3$$

$$\implies y=\sqrt2-\sqrt3$$